# WPF label binding not updating properly

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I know there are a thousand questions on the topic, but I cannot find what's wrong with mine...

I have a .xaml.cs file with the standard notify property changed stuff, a public member with the "notify" in the setter. I also set the data context in the constructor. Looks like this:

```
public partial class SlimERDplot : UserControl
{
   public SlimERDplot()
   {
      DataContext = this;
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   public enum AvailableImaginations { NotSet, Right, Left}
   private AvailableImaginations _movementImagination = AvailableImaginations.NotSet;

   //This is the one I'll be binding
   public string HemisphereUI { get { return Hemisphere.ToString() + " hemisphere"; } }


   public AvailableHemispheres Hemisphere
   {
      get { return _hemisphere; }
      set
      {
         if (_hemisphere != value)
         {
            _hemisphere = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HemisphereUI"); //tried with or without this, 
                                                    //makes no difference
         }
      }
   }
   


   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
       var handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The XAML simply:

```
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="{Binding Path=HemisphereUI}"></Label
```

Then from the consumer XAML I use it like this:

```
<UIControls:SlimERDplot x:Name="ERDRightDown" Hemisphere="Right" MovementImagination="Left" />
```

But in the label, it always says `NotSet` (the default value). I debugged, and the thing does get through the setter with the proper value, but the displayed value is never changed

What's missing?

Comment: You have a space after the I in  NotifyPropertyChanged("HemisphereUI ");

Comment: nice catch, but is not the problem. This appeared when copying here. Original code has no extra white space and still does not work.

Comment: If the instance assigned to DataContext does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, the view does not know how to subscribe for PropertyChanges of that DataContext, thats the reason for that interface. But you should not use that on controls ... the recommended way is to use `DependencyProperty`

Comment: Your `NotifyPropertyChanged` can override whatever you passed through. [CallerMemberName] does that. And is that a custom collection I see? `AvailableHemispheres` people have learned their lessons with those. Observable Collection is what you should use in WPF. And if you came from WinForm, you are in for a steep learning curve. Names are bad ju ju in WPF, they are there for animations and WinForms folk, so their heads don't explode.

Comment: it is an enum. Should I avoid those?

Comment: Not sure what this usercontrol is doing.  The properties etc could instead be in a viewmodel.  If you just have a label in a usercontrol then that seems like the usercontrol is just complicating things. The wpf equivalent to winforms label is actually a textblock.

Comment: Did you check the `propertyName` parameter has actually got the correct value? And enums are ok but Binding can be tricky when they are inside of a class because you have to use `+` sign. As for the answer that is done so you can bind things from VM, so you can control everything from VM rather than code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's missing?

Your `UserControl` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public partial class SlimERDplot : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
```

This is required for the view to actually subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: I guess they are right about the dependency thing. But for this little task, I refuse to write 200 lines of code to bind one label to one string. And adding this fixed the issue. If I go for something larger, I'll go with the view model path.

Comment: @javirs rather than getting discouraged explain what you are trying to do. Correct me if I'm wrong but you are trying to do a diagram of sorts? Use View Model approach with position, width height and use Canvas to store those. Then use templates and an observable collection to store them. All can be very easy.

Comment: I did not see where those 200 lines of code are ... the DependencyProperty is mostly written by a builtin makro **propdp** and only using the Hemisphere property we end up having 11 lines of code and we personally have to write 2 of them (the Changed method body). Thats it. In fact you are afraid in coding 2 lines

Comment: The plotting is a very complex plot that happens in a piece of C code, and I end up getting a bitmap. I just wanted to add a label in the top right corner saying what hemisphere is being used. I come from Blazor, where doing this is something like 20 characters of code, not lines.  You claim I only need to write 2 lines, but the other 25 lines are still there, to be debugged, code reviewed, and maintained. This is nonsense. Just because it its easy to type it, it does not mean it makes any sense.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [`DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dependency-properties)

Here an example

#### CodeBehind

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string HemisphereUI
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue( HemisphereUIProperty ); }
        private set { SetValue( HemisphereUIProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HemisphereUI.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HemisphereUIProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( HemisphereUI ), typeof( string ), typeof( MyUserControl ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

    public AvailableHemispheres Hemisphere
    {
        get { return (AvailableHemispheres)GetValue( HemisphereProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( HemisphereProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Hemisphere.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HemisphereProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( Hemisphere ), typeof( AvailableHemispheres ), typeof( MyUserControl ), new PropertyMetadata( AvailableHemispheres.NotSet, OnHemisphereChanged ) );

    private static void OnHemisphereChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        MyUserControl control = ( d as MyUserControl )!;
        control.HemisphereUI = e.NewValue.ToString() + " hemisphere";
    }
}

public enum AvailableHemispheres
{
    NotSet,
    Right,
    Left,
}
```

#### XAML

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="WpfApp1.Views.MyUserControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Views"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  d:DesignHeight="450"
  d:DesignWidth="800"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
  <Grid>
    <Label
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Content="{Binding HemisphereUI, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: WoW  this is bolloks ... At this point why should I care about binding at all .. I can modify the label's content in the OnHemisphereChanged... and.. really .. 200 lines of code to bind the label's content to one string in the backend? If that's the real solution for each single label in my UI, something is really wrong with WPF

Comment: Of course you can, I only showed you the whole (long) story.

Comment: "*I can modify the label's content in the OnHemisphereChanged*" - surely you could do that. Binding in a UserControl's XAML to the control's own properties is optional. Still, any property of a UserControl should be a dependency property in order to make it bindable and assignable from other sources like styles and animations.

Comment: Would that still be the case if using a viewmodel ?

Comment: You would bind the control's properties to the view model properties. Controls usually have no knowlegde of view models.

Comment: If you use a ViewModel, then you create a View for that ViewModel and wire up the binding in controls XAML. But in your example there was no ViewModel but a Control property. That is something different

Comment: Sure there's no VW in this example. I'm asking if by going the VM way I can avoid this terrible verbose approach

Comment: It depends. Some properties should not used by ViewModel directly like `Visibility`. The ViewModel has a boolean property which you bind to `Visibility` property and the converter controls, what `Visibility` you want/need for presentation, which may differ

Comment: But you are talking about a lot of code ... you started with a UserControl, code behind, properties, ... where a simple Label and a smart binding would be enough (a single line of XAML) ;o)